# JQuery Daterange picker do not show selected dates in input field

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery daterangepicker connected with an input field, when the user select a range, the input field get populated with the range chosen:

[image]

I would like, instead, that the input field *always* shows a text, something like "Please, select your dates..."

How can I achieve this?

```
  function addDays(date, days) {
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
    return result;
  }

  let departureDate, returnDate;            
  $(function () {
    $("#daterangepicker").daterangepicker(
      {
        opens: "top",
        minDate: addDays(new Date(), 7),
        locale: {
         format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
        },
      },
      function (start, end, label) {
        departureDate = start.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
        returnDate = end.format("DD-MM-YYYY");

        //alert("DEPARTURE: " + departDate + " RETURN : " + returnDate);
        document.getElementById("Departure-date").value = departureDate;
        document.getElementById("Return-date").value = returnDate;
      }
    );
  });
```

Comment: So you want the *input* to say "please select.." even after they select?  Why not just styled span/div or a readonly input?

Comment: Exactly, even after the select. What do you mean by a styled div or readonly input? I need the still the user to be able to click and select dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the examples on the [Date Range Picker site](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) is titled [*Input Initially Empty*](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#example5), and shows an empty input field - that seems related to what you want, so worth investigating.  Checking the code in that example shows it uses an option called `autoUpdateInput: false` - which sounds like exactly what you're trying to do.  So I tried it, and gave the input a placeholder with your suggested text, and it works fine.

```js
$('#daterangepicker').daterangepicker(
    {autoUpdateInput: false},
    function(start, end, label) {
        let departureDate = start.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
        let returnDate = end.format("DD-MM-YYYY");

        $("#Departure-date").val(departureDate);
        $("#Return-date").val(returnDate);
    }
);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" id="daterangepicker" placeholder="Please, select your dates ...">

<input type="text" id="Departure-date">
<input type="text" id="Return-date">
```